# Replace paragraph mark in string

Tags: python, replace

I have an html string and I am trying to replace a paragraph mark. I can do this manually in word by selecting edit > find what: `^p` > replace with `^s` > replace all. My question is how do I do this with an html string in python?

```
sample_html_string = "<html>
                  <title>
                  Hello
                  </title>
                  </html>"

correct_html_string = "<html><title>Hello</title></html>"
```

The issue is not simply solved using `re.sub` because I have a more complex html string that contains `li` tags and `p` tags, where I want to keep formatting.

Comment: Your example does not contain anything that looks like a "paragraph mark", nor does the result contain any nonbreaking space.  Are you just trying to remove whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\s+', '', sample_html_string)
'<html><title>Hello</title></html>"'
```

It'll replace all the space characters and perfectly works for your example

If you need to replace the paragraph mark (you mean `\n`, right?) you can use built-in `replace`:

```
>>> sample_html_string.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: thank you, your second suggestion using sample_html_string.replace solved the issue

Comment: OK, but you should learn what you're talking about. You said you wanted to relace a paragraph mark (`<p>`) with a nonbreak space (`&nbsp;`) but you were looking for something completely different.

Comment: @Matthias: in the mentioned context of Word, "paragraph mark" suggests `&para;`. But I agree that it was unclear.